Projection and inner products in stim
In Stim, is it possible to compute the inner product $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ of two stabiliser states $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$? It seems like this should be possible, since an algorithm to do this using the tableaus of these states is presented at the end of section III of Ref [1], but I have not been able to find a way in the Stim documentation.
Also, is it possible to compute the inner product/partial contraction over a restricted subset of qubits? For example, for a system with four qubits and states $|\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathrm{i}|0\rangle_1|0\rangle_2+|1\rangle_1|0\rangle_2)$ and $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle_1|0\rangle_2|1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4$ the inner product would be $$
\langle\phi|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-\mathrm{i}\langle0|_1\langle 0|_2+\langle 1|_1\langle 0|_2)|0\rangle_1|0\rangle_2|1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4 = -\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\sqrt{2}} |1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4,
$$
which lives in the Hilbert space of dimension $2^2$ spanned by the third and fourth qubits. (Another way to phrase this would be as the action of the operator $\mathcal{O}=\langle\phi|\otimes \text{Id}$ on $|\psi\rangle$, where $\text{Id}$ is the identity operator on qubits 3 and 4.)

[1] Improved Simulation of Stabilizer Circuits, S. Aaronson, D. Gottesman, Phys. Rev. A 70, 052328 (2004)

Wow, they really changed the built-in "duplicate question" auto comment to be a lot more accusatory rather than "does [link] answer your question".

Thanks! This definitely answers the first part of my question. I don't think it resolves the second part though, as the result of a partial inner product is not a tableau state in general (e.g. in my example the state is not correctly normalised). Is there any way to deal with this issue?

To get the partial overlap, run a circuit that maps the smaller state to $|0\rangle$ and then postselect on the Z axis of the qubits of the smaller state. Peek at expectations to determine overlap, and the remaining state will be in the upper qubits.
from typing import Optional, Tuple

import numpy as np
import stim


def partial_postselection(state: stim.Tableau, target: stim.Tableau) -> Tuple[float, Optional[stim.Tableau]]:
    sim = stim.TableauSimulator()
    sim.set_inverse_tableau(state**-1)
    sim.do_tableau(target**-1, targets=range(len(target)))

    coin_flips = 0
    for k in range(len(target)):
        z = sim.peek_z(k)
        if z == -1:
            return 0, None
        if z == 0:
            coin_flips += 1
        sim.postselect_z(k, desired_value=False)

    d = len(state) - len(target)
    for k in range(d):
        sim.swap(k, len(target) + k)
    sim.set_num_qubits(d)
    return 2**-coin_flips, sim.current_inverse_tableau()**-1

Testing it by comparing with einsum on the state vectors:
def test_fuzz():
    for _ in range(1000):
        n1 = 5
        n2 = 2
        state = stim.Tableau.random(n1)
        target = stim.Tableau.random(n2)
        overlap, conditioned_state = partial_postselection(state, target)

        actual_state = conditioned_state.to_state_vector(endian='big') if overlap > 0 else None
        actual_overlap = overlap

        state_vector = state.to_state_vector(endian='big').reshape(2**n2, 2**(n1 - n2))
        target_vector = target.to_state_vector(endian='big')
        expected_state = np.einsum("ij,i->j", state_vector, np.conj(target_vector))
        expected_overlap = np.linalg.norm(expected_state, 2)
        if expected_overlap < 1e-10:
            assert actual_state is None
        else:
            expected_state /= expected_overlap
            expected_overlap **= 2
            np.testing.assert_allclose(actual_overlap, expected_overlap, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-5)
            fidelity = abs(np.dot(actual_state, np.conj(expected_state)))
            np.testing.assert_allclose(1, fidelity, atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-5)

